# What electrical symbol where it looks like two resistors in parallel and connected on one end

Tags: symbol

I am trying to copy a circuit from a schematic but i stumbled upon a symbol that im not familiar of and the part label does not yield any relevant result from google

[image]

What is it and what does it do in the circuit?

Comment: it looks like US resistor array symbol mixed into otherwise IEC schematics. "NM" could stand for "not mounted", since jumper resistor is used to supply AREF.

Comment: so basically it is an open circuit in that part?

Comment: that would be my guess, yes. Unless that AREF wire is going somewhere important.

Comment: Looks like the analogue voltage reference input for an ADC.

Comment: I go with Maple's comment as well. The Jumper Resistor (JR1) of 0\$\Omega\$ shorts this BR1 component. So its value Not Mounted makes sense here. My best guess for reference designator BR would be Ballast Resistor, but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schematic symbols in production schematics more often  represent the  specific  component used and not necessarily the most elegant  logical schematic symbols.

This component is a 2 resistor array, specifically the type  where one side of the array is connected together (shorted) This component can be replaced by two resistors. Most major MFG of resistors offer arrayed parts,  with same value (e..g 4x 10k ) and with other patterns (2:1 or a resistor tree 8:4:2:1), independent terminals and with internal short like your example

This is done for a few reasons.

1. Manufacturers may offer  parts that  have better mutual tollerance than absolute tollerance, , e.g. a 10k/10k part to form a 2:1 divider ,  while the total resistance tolerance is say 1% the difference between the two halves may be guaranteed less than 0.1%
2. When you need lots of identical resistors, especially pull-up arrays, a quad resistor with 0805 shape (4x0805) takes up less space than 4x 0805 resistors, since they are all tied to Vdd or Vss anyway, the common connection is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this sort of structure used for populating mutually-exclusive surface-mount resistors. Rather than using two whole resistor footprints (four pads), the footprints are merged into one, but in a way that you can't easily place both resistors (three pads). Since this footprint is unique, it also needs a different symbol. However, you would need to know the context of the original drawer of the schematic.